# Can Goldberg algorithm in ocamlgraph be used to find Minimum Cost Flow graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, ocaml, graph-theory

I'm looking for an implementation to the Minimum Cost Flow graph problem in OCaml.

OCaml library [**ocamlgraph**](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/) has [Goldberg algorithm implementation](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/doc/Flow.Goldberg.html).

The paper called [Efficient implementation of the Goldberg-Tarjan minimum-cost flow algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.9897&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is noting that Goldberg-Tarjan algorithm can find minimum cost graph. Question is, **does ocamlgraph algorithm also find the minimum cost**? Library documentation only states, that it's suitable at least for the maximum flow problem.

If not, does anybody have a good link to a nice any minimum cost optimization algorithm code? I will manually translate it into OCaml then. Forgive me, if I missed it on Wikipedia: there are too many algos on flow networks for the first day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ocamlgraph currently doesn't provide such algorithm. This is a well-studied problem and there is plenty of code and descriptions on the net, also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cost_flow_problem) points to several possible approaches.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll look elsewhere then.